# Synfig change pivot point of imported SVG

Tags: inkscape, svg, import, synfig-studio

When I imported a graphic made in Inkscape into Synfig Studio, the pivot point of the object was a large amount of distance away. Is there anyway that I can move the pivot point of the imported object to the center of the object?

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. The object was not aligned in Inkscape. I just had to align it to the center of the page.